# CSS absolute positioning not functioning

Tags: css, html

I am learning some basic html and css and am trying to accomplish absolute positioning. However, my text is not changing its position even though I believe I used the right commands. Here is my code.

```css
 .content {
width:1200px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;

}

.post {
width:75%;
float: left;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-top: 30px;
border-right: solid black;
border-bottom: solid black;
position:relative;

}

.date {
position: absolute;
top = 10px;
right:  = 0px;

}
```

```html
    <div class = "content">
        <div class = "post">
            <h1> Hi </h1>
            <p class = "date">15 April 2025</p>
</div>
</div>
```

If this is not a sufficient amount of my code to find a solution, it would be appreciated if you simply leave a comment and I will provide you with the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is syntax problem in your `.date` selector. Should be:

```
.date {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks for the help!